# SSIS Expression Task functional however, not working in header

Tags: ssis, bids

I am trying to grab the date, and I have the expression working and returning the date.

I use an expression task to evaluate the date and set it to a Date variable,
(I have now changed this so that the header date is evaluated inside the variable expression and not as a separate task)

I use this in a flat file header portion and I include the variable inside of closed square brackets.
when I run the package--the variable name is returned.

I thought before that I was seeing it correctly calculate I guess my real question is why isn't this putting down the value, as I remember from the past you could use a variable inside of the header.

(i've also tried using [HeaderDate] [@User::HeaderDate] [HeaderDate] to no avail.)

Can anyone explain this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to modify a column header with an expression? If yes, then that is not possible as the column name is used to establish the pipeline and cannot be changed. Are you having an expression modify a column header but do not want it to? If yes, do you have 'column names in the first data row' selected in the file connection manager?

Comment: Sure I will post a screenshot, I do not have column names in the first data row selected because this is not my goal.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.   Please include all the steps a total stranger would need in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: I am not trying to modify a header column  I am trying to place a pre calculated headerdate value in the header row.  
Like i have a bunch of records, and at the top i want a header row that is just like.

Type, Date, Name of Submitter, etc
Then the row of 500 column data dump
and then a footer with the row count.  I have all of this done except the date is supposed to be generated because it will be running as a daily task.

Comment: Wait a sec, you are writing out data to flat file? And you are choosing this format for someone else to deal with? My answer is what it will take to read this monster. I'll leave it there to let it set in.

Comment: unfortunately, this monster of a data dump has requirements set by government @KeithL
But, trust me, I DO understand your sentiment

Comment: @JustinLe To my knowledge, dynamically modifying the header row to include the date is not possible. There are many reasons for this, and as KiethL alluded to, is bad design because other systems will have to ingest dynamic column names, which probably isn't possible either. The better solution here is to either include the date in the file name or to add a column for Date and populate each row with the date. Although, I did get a good laugh when you mentioned this is a government requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have messed with this quite a bit now and I have solved the problem.
It is possible to dynamically modify the header but you cannot do it inside of the flat file destination header.

You have to modify it inside of the data flow task expression..
So:
if you go to expressions you should be able to find the [Flat File Destination] . [Header]. and use this to set the value for this property dynamically.